# Is there any other way to stop persistence of field(which is also a domain class object) in a Grails domain class other than using transient keyword?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

```
class ContentA{
  String name
  ContentB[] contentBList
}

class contentB{
  Long typeId
  String typeName
}
```

Both ContentA and ContentB are domain objects which will be populated in respective calls
to the restful services we have.

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: [Lcom.classes.ContentB;, at table: table_name, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(content_b_list)

We get the above error when building the application.
When we add the ContentB to the `static transients{}` it is not rendered in the generated json string.  We use json calls to interact with service and convert the Domain objects to json
strings. Is there any other way to have the ORM stop persisting contentB?

We even tried to use CustomMarshaller for generating json string that didn't work out well.

Comment: You can put `contentB` into Sources:Groovy or your Controller directory and treat it as a `Command` object. If you annotate the class name with `@grails.validation.Validateable` you can then include `static constraints`, etc. and have the controller use it for validation. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects. I'm working on an app that does exactly this and persists its data in a backend service via JSON - there are no classes in my `Domain` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the association

```
class ContentA {
      String name
      static hasMany = [contentBList: ContentB]
}
```

[GORM oneToMany](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany)